# How to prevent Workbook_sheetChange event during Undo?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I am using Excel's "Workbook_SheetChange" event to take some information. Because I don't change any cell values by this function, Undo function is still working after this event.

However, when I undo, the "Workbook_SheetChange" is triggered. I don't want the event during undo. Is there a way to prevent "Workbook_SheetChange" event during undo?

Comment: Undo **is** changing the worksheet, so that gets flagged as a worksheet_change event as it is one.

Comment: How can I know the event is triggered by undo or other operations?